# Merging equi-partitioned data frames in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Hadoop a join/merge of large equi-partitioned data sets could be done without reshuffling and reduce phase simply using map-side join with CompositeInputFormat.

Trying to figure out to do it in Spark:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Seq(("D", 1), ("C", 2), ("B", 3), ("A", 4))).toDF("k", "v")
    .repartition(col("k")).cache()
val y = sc.parallelize(Seq(("F", 5), ("E", 6), ("D", 7), ("C", 8))).toDF("k", "v")
    .repartition(col("k")).cache()

val xy = x.join(y, x.col("k") === y.col("k"), "outer")

x.show()    y.show()    xy.show()

+---+---+   +---+---+   +----+----+----+----+
|  k|  v|   |  k|  v|   |   k|   v|   k|   v|
+---+---+   +---+---+   +----+----+----+----+
|  A|  6|   |  C| 12|   |   A|   4|null|null|
|  B|  5|   |  D| 11|   |   B|   3|null|null|
|  C|  4|   |  E| 10|   |   C|   2|   C|   8|
|  D|  3|   |  F|  9|   |   D|   1|   D|   7|
|  E|  2|   |  G|  8|   |null|null|   E|   6|
|  F|  1|   |  H|  7|   |null|null|   F|   5|
+---+---+   +---+---+   +----+----+----+----+
```

So far so good. 
But when I check execution plan I see "unnecessary" sorts:

```
xy.explain

== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeOuterJoin [k#1283], [k#1297], FullOuter, None
:- Sort [k#1283 ASC], false, 0
:  +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [k#1283,v#1284], InMemoryRelation [k#1283,v#1284], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(k#1283,200), None, None
+- Sort [k#1297 ASC], false, 0
   +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [k#1297,v#1298], InMemoryRelation [k#1297,v#1298], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(k#1297,200), None, None
```

Is it possible to avoid sorts here?

**Edit**

For the reference, Hadoop had this "feature" available since 2007:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-2085

**Update**

As Lezzar pointed out repartition() alone is not sufficient to achieve equi-partitioned sorted state.
I think now it needs to be followed by sortWithinPartitions()
So that should do the trick:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Seq(("F", 1), ("E", 2), ("D", 3), ("C", 4), ("B", 5), ("A", 6))).toDF("k", "v")
    .repartition(col("k")).sortWithinPartitions(col("k")).cache()
val y = sc.parallelize(Seq(("H", 7), ("G", 8), ("F", 9), ("E",10), ("D",11), ("C",12))).toDF("k", "v")
    .repartition(col("k")).sortWithinPartitions(col("k")).cache()
```

xy.explain()

```
== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeOuterJoin [k#1055], [k#1069], FullOuter, None
:- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [k#1055,v#1056], InMemoryRelation [k#1055,v#1056], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Sort [k#1055 ASC], false, 0, None
+- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [k#1069,v#1070], InMemoryRelation [k#1069,v#1070], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), Sort [k#1069 ASC], false, 0, None
```

No sorting anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saying unnecessary sort ? The merge join needs the data to be sorted. And in IMHO, there is not a better strategy than a merge join to perform a full outer join, except  if one of your dataframes is small enough to be broadcasted

Comment: When you merge two sorted sets, there is no need to sort. It is pretty much O(n). Moreover for equi-partitioned sets merge could be done locally for every partition.

Comment: Yes, but when did you sort your data ? you have only repartitioned it using your join key, but you have never done any sorting step. So there is no way spark could know that your data is sorted.

Comment: my understanding is that repartitioning is sorting data within a partition, try x.show() command

Comment: repartitioning doesn't necessarily sort the data. It only distributes it across the nodes according to a key. Even if by any chance the data has been found sorted after the repartitioning, the spark engine would never have been aware of that, because there isn't any sorting step that guaranties spark that the data is sorted.

Comment: You are right in a sense that repartition alone does not sort partitions. My assumption was wrong. According to the doc, this function is doing the same as DISTRIBUTE BY in hive. And to guarantee sort, DISTRIBUTE BY should be followed by SORT BY to achieve both equi-partitioned and sorted state for each partition

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Map-side joining in Hadoop, Spark has the broadcast join, which transfers table data to all the workers just like what distributed cache does in hadoop mapreduce.  Please refere spark Documentation or search once for spark broadcast hash join. Spark automatically takes care of it unlike the hive. So, no need to worry about it.

You will need to understand few parameters though for this.

-> spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold, the size under which, spark broadcasts the table automatically.

You can try below code to understand broadcast join and also you can refer spark Documentation for BroadCast join or google it for bit more details.

Example code to try:

```
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);
1) sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab3 (key INT, value STRING)")

2) sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO tab4 select 1,\"srini\" from sr23");
(I have created other table to just insert a record into table. As hive only support insert into select, i have used this trick to have some data.) You can skip this step as well, as you just want to see the physical plan.

------ You can also use any Hive table that is already created instead.. I am just trying to simulate the hive table thats it. --- 

3) val srini_df1 = sqlContext.sql("ANALYZE TABLE tab4 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOSCAN");

4) val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((5,"F"), (6,"E"), (7,"sri"), (1,"test"))).toDF("key", "value")

5) val join_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tab5").join(df2,"key");

6) join_df.explain
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(530360) called with curMem=238151, maxMem=555755765
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_23 stored as values in memory (estimated size 517.9 KB, free 529.3 MB)
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(42660) called with curMem=768511, maxMem=555755765
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_23_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 41.7 KB, free 529.2 MB)
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_23_piece0 in memory on localhost:63721 (size: 41.7 KB, free: 529.9 MB)
16/03/15 22:40:09 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 23 from explain at <console>:28
== Physical Plan ==
Project [key#374,value#375,value#370]
 BroadcastHashJoin [key#374], [key#369], BuildLeft
  HiveTableScan [key#374,value#375], (MetastoreRelation default, tab5, None)
  Project [_1#367 AS key#369,_2#368 AS value#370]
   Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#367,_2#368]
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, but my question is specific to two LARGE sets. Broadcast join simply does not make any sense unless one of the joined part is small enough.